# Checking if your code is running on 64-bit PHP

Tags: php

Does anyone know of a way of checking within PHP if the script is running as either 32-bit or 64-bit?  Currently I'm using PHP 5.3.5.

Ideally I'd like to write a function so my code can look like this:

```
if( is_32bit() === true ) {
    do_32bit_workaround();
}
do_everything_else();
```

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: it seems this question is answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353473/can-php-tell-if-the-server-os-it-64-bit

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Check the `PHP_INT_SIZE` constant. It'll vary based on the size of the register (i.e. 32-bit vs 64-bit).

In 32-bit systems `PHP_INT_SIZE` should be **4**, for 64-bit it should be **8**.

See http://php.net/manual/language.types.integer.php for more details.

Comment: @matb33 ...it's the same answer with a switch statement...?

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't say what the value of `PHP_INT_SIZE` should be for 32-bit vs. 64-bit. matb33's link provides that information.

Comment: This was useful for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16510636/php-convert-string-into-float-double

Comment: Quick command line check: `php -r 'echo (PHP_INT_SIZE===8)?"64 bit ":"32 bit ";'`

Comment: `phpinfo()` tells me I am on x64 architecture, but `PHP_INT_SIZE` gives me `4` and the Chris0 method gives me `32`. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 13):

You could write a function like this:

```
function is_32bit(){
  return PHP_INT_SIZE === 4;
}
```

Then you could use the sample code you posted:

```
if ( is_32bit() ) {
    do_32bit_workaround();
} else {
    do_everything_else();
}
```

Comment: Less is more, short answer is always the best answer.

Comment: `phpinfo()` tells me I am on x64 architecture, but `PHP_INT_SIZE` gives me `4` and the Chris0 method gives me `32`. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 13):

Here is an example that can be used from console

For Windows:

```
php -r "echo (PHP_INT_SIZE == 4 ? '32 bit' : '64 bit').PHP_EOL;" && php -i | findstr Thread
```

For Linux

```
php -r "echo (PHP_INT_SIZE == 4 ? '32 bit' : '64 bit').PHP_EOL;" && php -i | grep Thread
```

Output example:

```
64 bit
Thread Safety => disabled
```

Answer (score 8):

A short way to get the number of bits.

```
    strlen(decbin(~0));
```

How this works:

The bitwise complement operator, the tilde, **~**, flips every bit.

@see http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Using this on **0** switches on every bit for an integer.

This gives you the largest number that your PHP install can handle.

Then using decbin() will give you a string representation of this number in its binary form

@see http://php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php

and strlen will give you the count of bits.

Here is it in a usable function

```
function is32Bits() {
    return strlen(decbin(~0)) == 32;
}
```

Comment: Its good to know this way too, because it works even in PHP-Versions below 5.1