# Magento: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 90 bytes)

Tags: php, magento, out-of-memory, magento-1.4

I am seeing this error at the time of saving order only for a particular customer who is having large order history (around 300K past orders).

I have custom script to save the order programmatically.

The line I see problem is: $order->save();

```
$order->place();
$order->save(); // throwing error here
$orderId = $order->getIncrementId();
```

I looked into server questions/blogs for this and all saying increasing the php memory limit using;

```
php_value memory_limit
```

But that too doesn't works for me. I tried allocation 4GB to php memory but even than it fails.

Strange things is that only for particular customer.

Is there some problem with Magento API while saving order object?

Please advise.

Magento version: 1.4.2

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885191/how-to-increase-memory-limit-for-php-over-2gb

Comment: @ChetanAmeta, I tried all the options mentioned there except setting unlimited memory: ini_set('memory_limit', '-1') since that is production box. But no luck.

Comment: Sounds like a collection memory exhaustion issue. There are a couple modules out there that allow archiving orders older than a set date that you probably need to look into.