# PHP out of memory though I have MUCH MUCH more allocated

Tags: php, memory, drupal

I am getting the following error on my Drupal site:
`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 205668 bytes)`.

To be sure, 268,435,456 + 205,668 = 268,641,124 bytes = 256.2 MB.

In my php.ini I have `memory_limit = 2G`. I have verified that I am editing the correct php.ini file. When I xdebug the site and enter `ini_get('memory_limit');` into the console, I receive `2G` for the output. So I know my file is being read correctly.

I've also checked my `.htaccess` file to verify that there are no other memory directives in there. There are not. Where is this limit coming from?

Comment: whats `phpinfo();` say ?

Comment: The very same. 2G.

Comment: if the machine does not have the memory available, php can't use it, no matter the limit set.

Comment: The machine has 16G available — although I just figured out the problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this site has Drupal's `path_memory` module enabled, and the path I was trying to hit was configured to have a maximum of 256M available at `admin/config/system/path-memory`. Tricky.

Answer (score 0):

1) You sir must have a ton of memory to apply 2 gigs for EACH HTTP/PHP process.

2) php memory_limit does not accept 'G' as a proper setting, make it 2048M instead
[How to increase memory limit for PHP over 2GB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885191/how-to-increase-memory-limit-for-php-over-2gb)

Comment: Ah, good to know. Changing it to `2048M` gives me the same error, topping out presumably at `256M`. This is trying to recreate a feature on localhost.