# PHP - Memory Limit. Trying to read large file (72mb)

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a script processing large text files.
I am limited however by the size of the files.
I've done some searching on this forum, and i've come to the conclusion that i must process the file line by line, however this brings up quite a bit of issues for me, as i need some detailed info from the file, before i can start processing it.

I've tried adding each line to a variable as below:

```
$content = "";
$handle = fopen($target_File, "r") or die("Couldn't get handle");
if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fgets($handle, 256);
        // Process buffer here..
        $content .= $buffer;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

And just as expected, it did not work.

Could anyone help me out ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase memory limit for PHP over 2GB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885191/how-to-increase-memory-limit-for-php-over-2gb)

Comment: Well just adding the lines one by one to a string variable, is of course going to need roughly the same amount of memory, as if you had read it into a string in one go in the first place ... _“however this brings up quite a bit of issues for me, as i need some detailed info from the file, before i can start processing it”_ – well then you need to give us more details on that ...

Comment: The textfile is a gcode and the file contains information regarding how many layers etc. there is. It is this info i need to start doing my calculations.

Comment: Maybe you could read the file line by line (as you already do) and create a "plan" of your file. E.g. "layer1" data starts in file line 23 and so on. Later on you can directly access this line and read only the part you really need.

Answer (score 1):

add this on top of your file

```
ini_set("memory_limit", -1);
```

Be careful, the page can use all the RAM on the server

Comment: I've tried that - My Host does not allow any more than 1024M - regardless of my setting :/ And it still times out because of memmory (Out of memory (allocated 811859968) (tried to allocate 72 bytes))

Comment: Sorry i've done mistake. ini_set("memory_limit", -1)

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = "";
$handle = fopen($target_File, "r") or die("Couldn't get handle");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096))!== false) {
        // Process buffer here..
        $content .= $buffer;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

**OR**

```
$content = "";
$target_File ="/tmp/uploadfile.txt";
$handle = fopen($target_File, "r") or die("Couldn't get handle");

if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
        // Process buffer here.. 
        //$content .= $buffer;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

### NOTE:

> If the problem is caused by hitting the memory limit, you can try setting it a higher value (this could work or not depending on php's configuration).

this sets the memory limit to `32 Mb`

`ini_set("memory_limit","32M");`

Comment: Editing the buffer size does not make any difference, since its the servers memory limit that limits it.

Comment: It still gives me the same error :/

Seems like i'm just limited by the server!