# PHP memory_limit -1 does not work, seems to be 6GB

Tags: php, memory-limit

On a non production system I export data from a Magento shop using PHP script on CLI. Even if I use this settings

```
php -i | grep memory_limit
memory_limit => -1 => -1
```

or (for testing, if "-1" is a problem)

```
php -i | grep memory_limit
memory_limit => 9000M => 9000M
```

in my /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini, I get the following error:

**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 6290000000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 232422 bytes)**

Memory of the system using command "top":

```
KiB Mem : 20561176 total,  8667804 free,  7096968 used,  4796404 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  4190204 total,  4067004 free,   123200 used. 13050308 avail Mem
```

How can I increase the memory limit to really unlimited?

Exists other settings I don't know?

Comment: How do you export the data? To a file? What kind of format is used?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885191/how-to-increase-memory-limit-for-php-over-2gb

Comment: If your script consume so much esources then further increasing memory limit is a bad idea. Try to figure out why does it happen in the first place.

Comment: I export to a csv file. It size should be about 200 MB. I consumes so much memory because I have to to over all products in the Magento database with more than 300.000 items and build a huge collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a hard coded

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '6000M');
```

in the Magento code. Sorry for my question.