# composer runs out of memory, cannot work around

Tags: php, memory, composer-php, cygwin

I'm trying to install dependencies for a PHP command line tool with composer (installed in cygwin), but it runs out of memory no matter what I do.

I've increased `memory_limit` in `php.ini` to `2G`

I've tried running `php -d memory_limit=2G composer.phar` with

I've tried removing the limit altogether with `php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar ...`

It keeps thinking it only has 64M of RAM available to it: `Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 68681728) (tried to allocate 2147215 bytes)`

This machine as 24GB of RAM.

Comment: Try expressing the value in megabytes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885191/how-to-increase-memory-limit-for-php-over-2gb

Comment: What is returned by `php -i | grep 'memory_limit'`?

Comment: are you using the 64 bit version of cygwin ?

Comment: @dhinchliff: tried it, no difference.

Comment: @matzeri: no, still on 32-bit.  I'll try the 64-bit version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **matzeri**, the 64-bit cygwin seems to have done the trick.  Oddly, though, composer on 32-bit cygwin always ran out at only 64MB.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue and my guess is that it's some sort of bug in 32-bit cygwin's version of php.  I ran a very simple test script that allocated memory at different sizes.  When the allocation size is small, say less than 2MB, then I can allocate up to the memory_limit.  When the allocation size is slightly larger, say 6MB or more, it fails.