# PHP Out of memory vs Allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: php

I need help with a PHP memory problem.
Composer and Phan both fail with Out of memory errors on my windows 10 system running cygwin php 7.3.7.

[image]

I have my memory_limit set to 2G

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.3.7 (cli) (built: Jul 21 2019 18:10:35) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.7, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.9.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans

$ php -i | grep memory
memory_limit => 2G => 2G
Collecting memory statistics => No
```

And I have a simple program that tests the memory limits:

```
<?php
echo "Memory test...\n";
$argv = $_SERVER['argv'];
$step = $argv[1] * 1024 * 1024;
$a    = [];
while (1)
{
  echo "  ". memory_get_usage(true). " bytes used.  Allocating another ~$step bytes\n";
  $a[] = str_repeat('a', $step);
}
```

When I run this `php -f tmp/t.php 7` it predictably runs out of memory with the 'Allowed memory size exhausted' error at my 2G limit:

```
$ php -f tmp/t.php 7
Memory test...
  2097152 bytes used.  Allocating another ~7340032 bytes
  9502720 bytes used.  Allocating another ~7340032 bytes
  16908288 bytes used.  Allocating another ~7340032 bytes
 ...
  2105278464 bytes used.  Allocating another ~7340032 bytes
  2112684032 bytes used.  Allocating another ~7340032 bytes
  2120089600 bytes used.  Allocating another ~7340032 bytes
  2127495168 bytes used.  Allocating another ~7340032 bytes
  2134900736 bytes used.  Allocating another ~7340032 bytes
  2142306304 bytes used.  Allocating another ~7340032 bytes

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 7340064 bytes) in /cygdrive/c/Users/dschmidt/tmp/t.php on line 13

Call Stack:
    0.0005     403664   1. {main}() /cygdrive/c/Users/dschmidt/tmp/t.php:0
    0.8291 2140640320   2. str_repeat() /cygdrive/c/Users/dschmidt/tmp/t.php:13
```

But when I run it with `php -f tmp/t.php 8` it dies very early with the 'Out of memory' error after allocating a measly 10M:

```
$ php -f tmp/t.php 8
Memory test...
  2097152 bytes used.  Allocating another ~8388608 bytes
  10551296 bytes used.  Allocating another ~8388608 bytes

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 10551296) (tried to allocate 8388640 bytes) in /cygdrive/c/Users/dschmidt/tmp/t.php on line 13

Call Stack:
    0.0005     403664   1. {main}() /cygdrive/c/Users/dschmidt/tmp/t.php:0
    0.0055    8858240   2. str_repeat() /cygdrive/c/Users/dschmidt/tmp/t.php:13
```

Not sure what limit it is hitting but `composer update` hits a similar, but different, low limit:

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 57671680) (tried to allocate 2110325 bytes) in phar:///cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php on line 462
```

Comment: I don't have an answer, but my first thought was to search for "how to set memory limit when running php cli". There are a couple other StackOverflow questions that might help, such as running your command line with the memory limit argument included or to double-check that you are updating the correct php.ini. I'm reading in some articles that for CLI, it could be in a different spot.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43548976/how-do-i-set-the-memory-limit-for-php-cli-when-using-xampp

Comment: Is your php 32bits or 64bits? (x64 or x86) ?

Comment: The `-d memory_limit=2G` flag doesn't change anything.

The system is x64 based.

Comment: Is cygwin also 64 bit? 

I ask due to this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170263/composer-runs-out-of-memory-cannot-work-around

Comment: Yes, my cygwin install is 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I did another Cygwin update and it updated a bunch of php modules. That fixed my problem. I had done a Cygwin update just about 10 days ago so thee must have been a bug in that small window of Cygwin php modules.

Glad to have this fixed. Sorry to all those who spent time thinking about it for me.