# Allowed memory size of ... bytes exhausted - php

Tags: php

I am trying to install the dependencies to one of my existing projects in Laravel. I have already increased the memory size in php.ini to 2048M. But still, I am getting the following output when I am trying with the "composer install." Can anyone please let me know what to do next? I am running on ubuntu 18, apache2, and for this project, specifically PHP 5.6.

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted
> (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in
> /usr/share/php/Composer/Package/Link.php on line 60
>
> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried
> to allocate 32 bytes) in /usr/share/php/Composer/Package/Link.php on
> line 60
>
> Check
> https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors
> for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.ef-user

Comment: if it is a one time thing, you can set php.ini to give 90% of your total free memory and monitor memory usage to see how high it spikes. Aka, if you got 30GB free RAM, give it 27G.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increase memory limit for PHP over 2GB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885191/how-to-increase-memory-limit-for-php-over-2gb)

Comment: I have done the thing as @Dimi said. It worked for me.