# PHP Convert String into Float/Double

Tags: php, string, floating-point, implicit-conversion

I have list of string (size in bytes), I read those from file. Let say one of the string is 2968789218, but when I convert it to float it become 2.00.

This is my code so far :

```
$string = "2968789218";
$float = (float)$string;
//$float = floatval($string);
//the result is same
// result 2.00
```

Anyone?

### Solved

The problem was actually the encoding. It's fine now when I change the file encoding :D

Comment: Works just fine for me ?

Comment: It's no fine for me :'(

Comment: Did you try (int), or do you actually need a float ?

Comment: `(int)` in 32-bit system will cause overflow. Max value is 2147483647.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Surprisingly there is no accepted answer. The issue only exists in 32-bit PHP.

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion),

> If the string does not contain any of the characters '.', 'e', or 'E' and the numeric value fits into integer type limits (as defined by PHP_INT_MAX), the string will be evaluated as an integer. In all other cases it will be evaluated as a float.

In other words, the `$string` is first interpreted as INT, which cause overflow (The `$string` value **2968789218** exceeds the maximum value (`PHP_INT_MAX`) of 32-bit PHP, which is **2147483647**.), then evaluated to float by `(float)` or `floatval()`.

Thus, the solution is:

```
$string = "2968789218";
echo 'Original: ' . floatval($string) . PHP_EOL;
$string.= ".0";
$float = floatval($string);
echo 'Corrected: ' . $float . PHP_EOL;
```

which outputs:

```
Original: 2.00
Corrected: 2968789218
```

To check whether your PHP is 32-bit or 64-bit, you can:

```
echo PHP_INT_MAX;
```

If your PHP is 64-bit, it will print out `9223372036854775807`, otherwise it will print out `2147483647`.

Comment: It's not entirely clear. Is it necessary to store the `floatval` result in a variable instead of directly calling the function in echo?

Answer (score 9):

$float = floatval($string);

Ref : http://www.php.net/floatval

Answer (score 5):

Try using

```
$string = "2968789218";
$float = (double)$string;
```

Comment: @tegaralaga How are you checking result? The `.00` looks fishy.

Comment: `(double)` and `(real)` does'nt really exist in PHP, so casting to those will cast to `(float)` which is exactly what the OP is doing..

Comment: looking ok at my end. what platform you are using. Read more about [float](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php).

Comment: Is there something wrong with my server? I use free server from RedHat OpenShift https://frodo-baggins.rhcloud.com/info.htm

Comment: sorry but i am unable to figure out what causing this.

Comment: is your system 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: 64 bit. The problem was actually the encoding. Sorry, guys. It's fine now when I change the file encoding :D

Answer (score 0):

If the function floatval does not work you can try to make this :

```
    $string = "2968789218";
    $float = $string * 1.0;
    echo $float;
```

But for me all the previous answer worked ( try it in http://writecodeonline.com/php/ )
Maybe the problem is on your server ?