# What's the difference between floatval and (float) in php?

Tags: php, casting

I've got some strings that I need to cast as floats but have seen two apparently different ways of doing it:

```
$float = floatval ($float);
```

and

```
$float = (float) $float;
```

Are there any differences between the two methods?

Comment: (float) is 6 times faster. Hence, my advise is to use it instead of floatval()

Comment: @SimionZ Why is (float) faster ? Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

In all other cases it will be evaluated as a float. In other words, the $string is first interpreted as INT, which cause overflow (The $string value 2968789218 exceeds the maximum value ( PHP_INT_MAX ) of 32-bit PHP, which is 2147483647.), then evaluated to float by (float) or floatval()

Please have look at [PHP Convert String into Float/Double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16510636/php-convert-string-into-float-double)

The best answer for this is [Typecasting vs function to convert variable type in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30940148/typecasting-vs-function-to-convert-variable-type-in-php)

Comment: interesting information, however it **does not answer** the question in any way. should have been a comment. (also, since it only occurs on 32-bit installations of PHP, it probably only affects a small percentage of systems.)