# Conversion failing from string to float/double

Tags: php, type-conversion

I have issue with my conversion from string to double/float. It is so strange when I run application on my local machine it working great. But when I run it on Hosting4Real hosting it making so much decimals.
E.g.
code

```
$number = "5.30";
$convNum  = (float)$number;
echo $convNum;
```

output

```
5.29999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875
```

I have tried number_format() and it works but it's converting to string, I have tried with round and nothing happens.
It's so strange and logic wired that I can't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: How did you try with `round()`?

Comment: Floats are notoriously unreliable due to rounding precision. There’s [a guide](https://floating-point-gui.de/) that explains why this happens.

Comment: "unitNetPrice" => round((double)data_get($arg, 'unik.price', 0),2),

Comment: Yes but how if it works great on my local machine with standard, how can it be different on hosting server. And how to make it double because it is important  API post because they only accept decimal.

Comment: please check if this help you or not -https://stackoverflow.com/a/24018780/3200792

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: I would suggest not using floats for representing money unless you like losing a lot of pennies.

Comment: As for the reason why it looks like that, see @TangentiallyPerpendicular's link, and [this example](https://3v4l.org/Hi9Ma) illustrating the effect of your provider's high setting for [`precision`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of casting, I'd use [`floatval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php).

```php
$number = "5.30";
$convNum = floatval($number);
echo $convNum; // 5.3
```

If you're wanting to retain decimal point precision, you can use [`number_format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) in conjunction.

```php
$number = "5.30";
$convNum = number_format(floatval($number), 2); // 2 dp
echo $convNum; // 5.30
```

Comment: There isn't any difference in using (float) or floatval() in this case. The type cast may even be faster than the function call to floatval as it has the functions overhead.