# the difference about PHP on 32 and 64 architecture?

Tags: php, c

i want to know the internal impliment of php, for example ,
the int length, the CRC method, or the Memory Managment....
when i write php, i do not know the difference ,but in fact it is difference on 32 and 64 
architecture.
Some one can tell me ?
or for example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423848/checking-if-your-code-is-running-on-64-bit-php

Comment: The suckage is wider on 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that on 64-bit PHP, the int type is 64 bits, while on 32-bit, it's 32 bits. This shows when a function uses all 32 bits of the type, such as the crc function - if you print out the value, it will be positive under 64-bit, while it might be negative (if the MSB is 1) on 32-bit. The overflow (PHP_MAX_INT) will also be different depending on the version. There has been some discussion on fixing this and automagically promoting a 32-bit value to 64-bit value even on 32-bit architectures iirc.

The comment on your question shows how you can determine if you're on 32- or 64-bit PHP.