# File not uploading in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have install **wampp.**
I want to upload more than **10 gb** file.
I have done following changes to the file.

> max_upload_filesize 64000M 
>  post_max_size 65000M 
>  memory_limit 60000M

In add media it is showing max upload size 63 gb
but following error is occuring while uploading

> File is empty. Please upload something more substantial. This error
>   could also be caused by uploads being disabled in your php.ini or by
>   post_max_size being defined as smaller than upload_max_filesize in
>   php.ini.

Dont say restart the sever i have done it many time.

Comment: Have you set `max_execution_time = 0` and `max_input_time = 0`? I assume you've built PHP as 64-bit?

Comment: what do you mean by php as 64-bit

Comment: wamp can be 32-bit or 64-bit. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423848/checking-if-your-code-is-running-on-64-bit-php