# Does the PHP Built-in Webserver have a memory limit?

Tags: php, phpstorm, php-builtin-server

I am locally hosting PHP scripts in PhpStorm using the "PHP Built-in Web Server" configuration. One script needs much memory, so I added `ini_set('memory_limit', 8589934592); # 8GiB` at the beginning  of it (Setting it works, I checked it with `ini_get('memory_limit')`).

But when I request the referring url, the execution of the script fails with the following error message in the error log:

`PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 1793064960) (tried to allocate 8334 bytes) in ...`

It is only able to allocate about 1.7GiB.

Does anybody know, why this happens? I assume that the PHP Built-in Webserver has a memory limit, but I cannot find anything about that.

---

PS: I'm using PHP v5.6, Windows 8 and PhpStorm 10.0.3

---

Edit:
My PC has about 10Gib free RAM to use

Comment: Very interesting question - I'm curious to see a proven answer.  From what you've observed (and tested), I'd guess the answer is a resounding "Yes, and it isn't well documented"...

Comment: I think a better alternative is to configure at the `php.ini` level and for your case you should be looking for `php.ini for your cli`. On my ubuntu is located at `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`, you'll have to look for mac.

Comment: Besides my problem seems to be solved by now, I don't want to change the `'memory_limit'` in the `php.ini`, because the default should not allow such a high memory usage. It is an exception for this single script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you run the webserver in 32 bit? If so, it might only be allowed to use max. 2 GB:
[How much memory can a 32 bit process access on a 64 bit operating system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639540/how-much-memory-can-a-32-bit-process-access-on-a-64-bit-operating-system)

I think you can check this with the PHP_INT_SIZE constant: 
[Checking if your code is running on 64-bit PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423848/checking-if-your-code-is-running-on-64-bit-php)

Comment: Woha, that seems to be it! Did not think of that. Yep, my Php is running in 32 bit