# Why does a simple PHP unset() memory test utilize twice the amount of memory in PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, memory-management

I was testing out whether unset() affects memory while the script is running, to see if unset() or other known method, $var=null is more efficient. unset() did affect memory, but since I tested it out on two different virtualhosts, I wondered why does one take more or less twice the amount of memory for the same script? I'm guessing the answer is something simple, but it escapes me at the moment. Script itself is below:

```
<?php

$init=memory_get_usage();
$test=array();
for($i=0;$i<=100000;$i++){
    $test[$i]=rand(0,10000000);
}
echo 'MEMORY CHANGE: '.((memory_get_usage()-$init)/1024/1024).'MB<br/>';

for($i=0;$i<=100000;$i++){
    unset($test[$i]);
}
echo 'MEMORY CHANGE: '.((memory_get_usage()-$init)/1024/1024).'MB<br/>';

//output on PHP 3.2.5 virtualhost:
//MEMORY CHANGE: 6.98558807373MB
//MEMORY CHANGE: 0.500259399414MB

//output on PHP 5.3.5 virtualhost
//MEMORY CHANGE: 13.970664978MB
//MEMORY CHANGE: 1.00063323975MB

?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you reset `$init` in between the loops?

Comment: And if you use memory_get_usage(true) rather than memory_get_usage()?

Comment: Same thing happens. 
3.2.5:
MEMORY CHANGE: 7.25MB
MEMORY CHANGE: 1MB
3.3.5:
MEMORY CHANGE: 14.25MB
MEMORY CHANGE: 1.75MB

There must be something about the server, but I don't know what to look for.

Comment: Just tested it myself. I dont know, where it comes from, but with `unset($temp);` at the end it frees much more memory. I assume, that if you just unset single indices it will not reduce the array itself (even if theire value is `void`, `null` or whatever is used internally). This means, that at least 100.000 hash-keys (arrays are hash-maps in PHP) are held in the memory as long as `$temp` exists.

Comment: True, but the main problem here is why does one server allocate twice the amount of memory for the very same script. I downgraded the PHP 5.3.5 server to 5.2.17 and it still shows taking twice the amount of memory in comparison. So it doesn't look like a PHP version thing, but a PHP or server setting of some sort.

Comment: One possibility would be that you're running a 32bit build of 5.2.17, and a 64 bit build of 5.3.5.  This would mean that each integer takes double the amount of space (8 byte ints vs 4 byte ints).  That could explain the nearly exactly double number you're seeing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP 3.2.5? That's so old it doesn't even reach the stone age. PHP's guts underwent a total re-write with the Zend engine, so even though the language itself stayed relatively the same, you're comparing two different environments.

But in case that version number is a typo, then possibly it's a 32bit v.s. 64bit host, which doubles the size of ints and could account for your purported 2x difference.

Comment: Can I tell the difference from phpinfo()? The 3.3.5 says about the system "Linux sn19 2.6.18-194.32.1.el5 #1 SMP Wed Jan 5 17:52:25 EST 2011 x86_64" and 3.2.5 says "Linux cloud-212-47-211-132.netpoint.ee 2.6.35 #1 SMP Fri Aug 6 23:39:12 EEST 2010 x86_64 "

Comment: Well, the hosts are obviously 64bit. To check from within PHP, try the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353473/can-php-tell-if-the-server-os-it-64-bit

Comment: Alright, I downgraded the PHP 5.3.5 server to 5.2.17 and it still shows taking twice the amount of memory in comparison. This is strange. So it doesn't look like a PHP version thing, but a PHP or server setting of some sort. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, this was a 64bit vs 32bit situation. Thank you! Does this mean I should double PHP's memory limits if it runs on 64bit as well?