# Find Windows 32 or 64 bit using PHP

Tags: php, windows

Is it possible to get the window processor bit??
I want to find the window processor bit using php??
I have coding to find the operating system and other properties.
Kindly advice.
Thanks -
Haan

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353473/can-php-tell-if-the-server-os-it-64-bit

Comment: Server or client properties? See @Arend's link for server, for client you would pretty much be limited to whatever info is in the user agent header (without using some kind of plugin).

Comment: Do you need to know whether the OS is 32/64 bit or the processor? A 64 bit processor could be running a 32 bit OS.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Assuming that you want to know the bitness of the PHP executable (not the microprocessor or the operating system):

*Generally speaking*, the size of an [integer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) should be 4 bytes on 32-bit and 8 bytes on 64-bit platforms:

```php
switch (PHP_INT_SIZE) {
    case 4:
        echo '32-bit version of PHP';
        break;
    case 8:
        echo '64-bit version of PHP';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'unusual PHP_INT_SIZE ' . PHP_INT_SIZE;
        break;
}
```

You may also look at the output of `phpinfo(INFO_GENERAL)`. Search the `Architecture` and `Configure Command` lines for keywords such as i586, x86_64, AMD64, x86 and x64.

Comment: If you use this code in a function, you may want to throw an exception in the default case, as it is not safe to determine the if its 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: Unfortunately, even when running 64-bit PHP on windows, integers are still limited to 32-bit, so you actually have no way of determining which type of PHP is installed (for Win only).You can however make an educated guess based on the limitation of the Operating system (e.g. if you're on 32-bit windows, you could not be running 64-bit PHP)

Comment: @doublehelix This is no longer correct.  As of Win10.1709, echo PHP_INT_SIZE on a x64 platform reports 8 bytes.  However, it also helps to be running a 64-bit version of PHP as well.

Comment: UPDATE: As of PHP 7.0 64-bit (8-byte) integers are now fully supported on the Windows platform. PHP 7 was not released until December 2015. Back in 2014 PHP 5 was not capable of this.

Comment: This answer is technically incorrect because the size reported corresponds to the PHP process and it's possible to run 32-bit code in a 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 7):

A slightly shorter and more robust way to get the number of bits.

```
    strlen(decbin(~0));
```

How this works:

The bitwise complement operator, the tilde, **~**, flips every bit.

@see http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Using this on **0** switches on every bit for an integer.

This gives you the largest number that your PHP install can handle.

Then using decbin() will give you a string representation of this number in its binary form

@see http://php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php

and strlen will give you the count of bits.

Here is it in a usable function

```
function is64Bits() {
    return strlen(decbin(~0)) == 64;
}
```

Comment: What makes this more robust than `PHP_INT_SIZE`?

Comment: Again, this reports the capability of the PHP process rather than OS.

Comment: @jdp PHP_INT_SIZE was introduced in 5.0.5. decbin has been around since version 4.

Comment: @sootsnoot `PHP_INT_SIZE` is around since v4.4. But nevertheless, no one should be using PHP v4 anyways.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the `COM` extension installed (in php.ini) you can call the windows WMI service.

*(Remember though that you event if you have a 64-bit processor, 64-bit OS and 64-bit PHP, your integers are still going to be 32-bit due to a limitation in x64-PHP on Windows.)*

Anyway...

To check the OS:

```
function getOsArchitecture() {
    $wmi = new COM('winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}//./root/cimv2');
    $wmi = $obj->ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem');
    if (!is_object($wmi)) {
        throw new Exception('No access to WMI. Please enable DCOM in php.ini and allow the current user to access the WMI DCOM object.');
    }
    foreach($wmi as $os) {
        return $os->OSArchitecture;
    }
    return "Unknown";
}
```

or, check the physical processor:

```
function getProcessorArchitecture() {
    $wmi = new COM('winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}//./root/cimv2');

    if (!is_object($wmi)) {
        throw new Exception('No access to WMI. Please enable DCOM in php.ini and allow the current user to access the WMI DCOM object.');
    }
    foreach($wmi->ExecQuery("SELECT Architecture FROM Win32_Processor") as $cpu) {
        # only need to check the first one (if there is more than one cpu at all)
        switch($cpu->Architecture) {
            case 0:
                return "x86";
            case 1:
                return "MIPS";
            case 2:
                return "Alpha";
            case 3:
                return "PowerPC";
            case 6:
                return "Itanium-based system";
            case 9:
                return "x64";
        }
    }
    return "Unknown";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function like this:

```
function is_32bit(){
  return PHP_INT_SIZE === 4;
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
if( is_32bit() ) {
    // do 32 bit stuffs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function bits() {
  return PHP_INT_SIZE * 8;
}

echo 'Php running on '.bits(). ' bits system';
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
function IsAtLeast64Bit()
{
    return defined('PHP_INT_SIZE') && PHP_INT_SIZE >= 8;
}
```

It returns only TRUE, if PHP_INT_SIZE is defined. This should apply for all 64-Bit systems. Future systems with more than 64 bits are managed too.

Answer (score -2):

`<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; ?>`
it is contained in the variable, you could explode that and derive it from that

Comment: Note:  this will tell you whether the client is running a 32/64 bit OS, not the server.

Comment: I think that is what he asked, he wants to know if his client is using a 32/64 bit OS to alter something.