# Xdebug with PhpStorm IDE - detects incoming connection but will not bring up debug console

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug, phpstorm

I have tried to set up Xdebug (2.2.3) with PhpStorm 7.0 and I cannot bring up the step-through debugging console as I have in the past. The guides that I have used to set this up are:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/configuring-xdebug.html
- http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/02/zero-configuration-debugging-with-xdebug-and-phpstorm-2-0/

I know that the Xdebug extension itself is working as the cachegrind.out.3280 files are being created on page load (with 12Mb litany of all of the scripts required and variables/values). My set up in php.ini (php version 5.4.12) is:

```
zend_extension="c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="c:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name="cachegrind.out.%p"
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=xdebug
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_host=dashboard.dev
```

After setting a break point, turning on Xdebug chrome extension, clicking to listen to Xdebug within PhpStorm and refreshing, I get the Incoming Connection from Xdebug dialogue:

[image: Incoming Connection from Xdebug]

However, when I click Accept, the dialogue disappears and nothing happens.

If I then go to Settings / PHP / Servers in PhpStorm, I see that a new entry has been created:
[image: Settings / PHP / Servers in PhpStorm]

Only by deleting the entry that was added can I get the Incoming Connection dialogue to show up again when I refresh the page. I notice that the port is set to 80 so wondering if that is right since the Xdebug extension is set to run over port 9000; when I click "Validate remote environment" select deployment server, then "Validate", I get: No debug extension is loaded. So I am assuming that the problem is something related to how this is set up.

Comment: 1) xdebug port (9000) and website port (80) are two DIFFERENT things. You should learn some basics first: http://xdebug.org/docs/ 2) `xdebug.remote_host=dashboard.dev` that's actually wrong -- it should be your IP address / domain name, not your website domain. it works only because it points to the same IP as your computer (127.0.0.1). 3) *"Only by deleting the entry that was added can I get the Incoming Connection dialogue to show up again"* -- that's correct and works exactly as it should.

Comment: Now: 1) what is your PHP (not version number) -- is it 32 bit or 64 ? 2) Please show output of your `phpinfo();` when executed via web interface (in a browser). Af far as I see it so far -- it should work for you OK -- I mean, it picks up incoming debug request. So .. what's happening after -- does it breaks on breakpoint? What will happen if you put `xdebug_break();` in your code (programmatic breakpoint) ?

Comment: Nice pointers - my php is 32bit (PHP_INT_SIZE = 4) and, to my surprise, xdebug_break() gets the debugger console to work (but the red circle breakpoints do not).

Comment: 1) Please show a screenshot with breakpoints -- maybe you have set them on a line where xdebug is unable to break (due to a bug or (most likely) the way how PHP itself generates bytecode); 2) *"php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll"* -- this tells me that you are using **64-bit xdebug on 32-bit PHP** -- it should not work, at all. Double check header table of `phpinfo()` output -- it should tell what `Architecture` your PHP is.

Comment: okay, well the Architecture is x64 so 64 bit ... I had used the accepted response to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303241/find-windows-32-or-64-bit-using-php which suggested that PHP_INT_SIZE = 4 indicates 32 bit but not necessarily reliable I suppose.

Comment: The breakpoint had been on a  `try` clause and after moving it to a class instantiation it is working.

Comment: So it's solved -- NOT a PhpStorm issue (and NOT xdebug one either) -- must be the way how PHP itself generates the byte-code -- if you check xdebug Issue Tracker you will find more examples.

Comment: Yes, it is working for me now. Thanks for your help. Do you have any links to how php's byte-code relates to debugging? I don't know anything about how the breakpoint is encoded within the php script when run by the server - I've just used it in IDEs and it usually works!

Comment: *"how php's byte-code relates to debugging?"* -- PHP generates such byte-code (op-code?) that xdebug is unable to insert breakpoint correctly (sometimes at all). Some links from PhpStorm's Issue Tracker: 1) http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=869 2) http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=949 3) http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-20398 4) http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-20743 5) http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-2191 6) http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-4721

Comment: Since issue s resolved -- consider answering it with the way how you have resolved your problem -- answered questions have higher priority in search and may help other people in similar situation. **Thank you.**

Answer (score 4):

The problem was fixed by adding the break points to other parts of the code as it was not working when attached to the `try` clause. Additionally, here are some other tips that might be useful:

1. Try using a programmatic breakpoint: xdebug_break();
2. Check that if your php is 32bit then so is the version of Xdebug (or that they are both 64 bit).
3. The xdebug remote host setting relates to the server IP address (so 127.0.0.1 for local).

Comment: "The xdebug remote host setting relates to the server IP address (so 127.0.0.1 for local)." - What do you mean by this? I always thought we needed to put the ip of the connecting client here?

Answer (score 3):

In your Phpstorm goto **File** > **Settings** > **Languages & Frameworks** > **PHP** > **Debug**.

Under **External conections** section, mark the checkbox saying

> Ignore external connections through unregistered server configurations

This was fixed for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the mapping between server path and local path in preferences / server