# base64_encode/decode is not working correctly

Tags: php, base64

I am trying to use `base64_encode` to display the ids differently. I am also trying to add a large number to the id so the string will look longer.

The problem is I encrypt a number to make it a string. Then when I decrypt the same string I expect the same value but in my case it is returning different values.

Why I am not seeing the same values?

This is my code:

```
define('IDS_SALT', 852045641596357);

function simple_encode($id){
    $data = '';
    $id += IDS_SALT;
    $data = base64_encode($id);
    $data = str_replace(array('+','/','='),array('-','_','.'),$data);
    return $data;
}


function simple_decode($code){
    $data = '';
    $code = str_replace(array('-','_','.'),array('+','/','='),$code);
    $id = base64_decode($code);
    $id -= IDS_SALT;
    return $id;
}

//this is returning "OC41MjA0NTY0MTU5NjM2RSsxNA.."
echo 'Encrypted: ';
echo  simple_encode(7);
echo '<br />';

//this is returning 3 a NOT 7. it should return 7
echo 'Encrypted: ';
echo  simple_decode(  simple_encode(7)  );
echo '<br />';
```

Comment: Your salt integer is WAY outside the supported range for a 32bit PHP install, which maxes out at a signed 32bit int of 2,147,483,647. Do an `echo IDS_SALT` to see what really got stored in it.

Comment: I did echo number_format(IDS_SALT, 0 , '', ''); and it displayed the same number i stored in IDS_SALT

Comment: Marc B is spot on - just swapped to a 32 bit machine and the salt is not stored as specified.

Comment: My Server is 64bit, does this mean that my php is 32bit but my server is 64bit? how can I check my php bit size?

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303241/find-windows-32-or-64-bit-using-php - will tell you how to check bit size...

Comment: 32-bit version of PHP :( I should probably upgrade this to a 64-bit since my machine is 64-bit. also when I made the number smaller it worked!

Comment: That'd do it. Glad you're sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the same code (exactly as above) on my test server here - I received different results:

> Encrypted: ODUyMDQ1NjQxNTk2MzY0
>
> Encrypted: 7

Which looks to be correct?

Is there any other code in your test script that could be interfering?

Steve

Comment: Thanks Steve, I am not sure if we are running different php version that is making the different or not. When I run the code above I see the following Encrypted: OC41MjA0NTY0MTU5NjM2RSsxNA..
Encrypted: 3

Comment: Possibly - I'm running PHP 5.3 this end.