# Converting the digit from Number format to Scientific Notation is wrong

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

**[A1] = 2519121152247150000000**

`$data = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, 1)->getValue()`

Return `$data = 2.51912115225E+21`

But it's must be `$data = 2.51912115224715E+21`

Comment: What is your precision setting in php.ini?

Comment: Note that you may well also get a difference between 32-bit PHP and 64-bit PHP

Comment: 64-bit version of PHP, [i am using this function to check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6303785/3599373)

Comment: Then check your `precision` setting in `php.ini`.... I suspect it's set to 12, if you change it to 14 then you'll get all of those digits displayed.... [demo](https://3v4l.org/laa2R)

Comment: @MarkBaker You are the best !!
it's Work :D

`precicion = 12 in php.ini`
i change it and it's work

Thank YOU !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @MarkBaker

> Then check your precision setting in php.ini.... I suspect it's set to 12, if you change it to 14 then you'll get all of those digits displayed....

[DEMO from @MarkBaker](https://3v4l.org/laa2R)