# Connect SQL Server 2012 with PHP version 8.1.1

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I  have added this 2 lines

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_81_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_81_ts_x64.dll
```

inside my `php.ini` file and than I have added this 2 files inside in drivers too. It is not getting connected with SQL Server 2012 and PHP version which I am using is 8.1.6.

Any help will highly appreciated.

Error message:

> call to undefined function sqlserv

Comment: make sure you are matching thread safety and architecture. You can check if you are using TS (thread safe) or NTS(non-thread safe) in `phpinfo()` under Thread Safety. You can check architecture using answers in e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303241/find-windows-32-or-64-bit-using-php

Comment: @apokryfos i am using TS(thead safe) and  64-bit version of PHP

Comment: @apokryfos thanku my connection got established

Comment: Slight detour....sql server 2012 has less than a month left in extended support. It is past time for you to figure out an upgrade strategy.